# How do I include a list of nodes in Webform, with multiple fields per node / views row?

Tags: views, nodes, webforms, 9

In a Drupal 7 project, I had used the webform_view (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_view) module to list a number of nodes in a webform with a "quantity" and "size" field for each node/row to create a simple product order form. The form structure looks something like this...

```
[Node 1 description (from view)]
[Node 1 quantity number field]
[Node 1 size select field (options drawn from node content)]

[Node 2 description (from view)]
[Node 2 quantity field]
[Node 2 size select field (options drawn from node content)]

...
```

The time has come to re-create the site in Drupal 9, and it doesn't appear any similar module exists for D8/9. Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality? I'm trying to avoid using Drupal Commerce for such a simple order form.

Thanks!

Comment: How certain are you that this is not possible in Drupal 9? I don't know all the features but I noticed this issue, which suggests this is possible: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3024470

Comment: Hi @cilefen - Thanks for the reply. I am not certain at all. I will read through that issue report and see if it provides any clues. Thanks!